# Putting List Results into Objects

Tags: android, json

I am receiving a response from my server that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "559d443abae4f14958f6a854",
        "owner": "559d4323bae4f14958f6a852",
        "__v": 0,
        "updated_at": "2015-07-08T15:39:38.370Z",
        "expiration_date": "2015-07-13T17:07:59.933Z",
        "address": "",
        "company": "",
        "problemCode": "",
        "devices": [],
        "active": true,
        "description": "",
        "ticketNumber": "",
        "coordinateY": "",
        "coordinateX": ""
    },
    {
        "_id": "559d4ffaddd30e5f585dd1cf",
        "owner": "559d4323bae4f14958f6a852",
        "__v": 0,
        "updated_at": "2015-07-08T16:29:46.087Z",
        "expiration_date": "2015-07-13T17:08:00.287Z",
        "address": "",
        "company": "",
        "problemCode": "",
        "devices": [],
        "active": true,
        "description": "",
        "ticketNumber": "",
        "coordinateY": "",
        "coordinateX": ""
    }
]
```

I need to be able to put these results into a RecyclerView of objects that I can edit. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an `Java` class which contain the field in the response from `Server` and then use Gson lib to parse it.
Refer [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to say this is the best way to do it, but you can accomplish this by using [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) which is what I use 90% of the time. Using retrofit, you can convert your json to POJO's automagically. Then you can use those POJO's as the data for your recyclerview. Essentially, you will have a `List<MyObject>` that you can pass from retrofit to the Recycler View's adapter.

Comment: Never heard of it before but it looks really cool! What specifically should I write once I install it? Is there perhaps a good step-by-step or video tutorial available? A really good example class?

Comment: @syllablecake This tutorial can probably get you going better than anything I can write off the top of my head: http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/ Please don't forget to accept my answer if it satisfies your question. Good luck!